# How to pull row from join when foreign key is null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have a DB table with product information, and a DB table with tax rates.

My problem is that I am joining these two tables together, which works great.. until I disable "taxable" on a row for the product DB.  Now my query is trying to join, but doesn't find a foreign key and I get no result at all..  I want to grab a result either way.  I am using code igniter syntax, but it should be pretty obvious whats going on here:

```
    $this->db->from('inventoryTaxRates a');
    $this->db->join('inventory_items q', 'q.inventoryTaxRateID = a.inventoryTaxRateID');
```

sometimes q.inventyTaxRateID becomes 0, or disabled.. The query cannot join the two tables and gives me no result whatsoever.  I want it to still give me the result from inventory_items.

I have tried left joining as well:

```
 $this->db->join('inventory_items q', 'q.inventoryTaxRateID = a.inventoryTaxRateID', 'left');
```

Comment: There are different join types, so take the right one. See as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a RIGHT join like this:

```
$this->db->join('inventory_items q', 
                'q.inventoryTaxRateID = a.inventoryTaxRateID', 
                'right');
```

Answer (score 1):

You [can use RIGHT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673552/436932), but I'd like to rewrite query like that:

```
SELECT .. FROM inventory_items ...
LEFT JOIN inventoryTaxRates ...
```